# return a string having maximum possible value by using elements of the array for ex for a[]={3,5,34,30,9} you will return "9534330" not working

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

```cpp
bool comp(int a,int b)
{
    return to_string(a)+to_string(b)>to_string(b)+to_string(a);
}

string Solution::largestNumber(const vector<int> &a)
{
    sort(a.begin(),a.end(), comp);
    string ans="";
    for(auto i=a.begin();i<a.end();i++)
    {
        ans+=to_string(*i);
    }
    return ans[0]=='0'? "0" : ans;
}
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow! What makes you say this is not working? Does it crash when you run it? Or does it run, but returns the wrong result? Can you please include the error message or the test case with wrong output? Also, please provide a minimum reproducible example; i.e., a c++ code with a main() function and a definition of vector a. This way, your code could be executed and it is easier to answer.

Comment: Also please note it is probably safer to write `i != a.end()` rather than `i<a.end()` for the loop condition, although the latter might work as well.

Comment: it is a showing a huge long error and i actually i can,t understand that error.

Comment: it is a question from interview here is the link https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/largest-number/

Comment: Please include that error message in your question. We can't guess the error.

Comment: error is too long to post here

Comment: You will not get any answer to your problem if you refuse to state what your problem is. Do not post the error message in a comment. Use the `edit` button to add the error message to the text of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You program works, after removing the `const` of `const vector<int> &a`. A constant vector cannot be modified and `std::sort` tries to modify it.

If you cannot modify the signature of the function, you can directly copy and create a new `vector<int>`.

A better solution consists in creating a `std::vector<std::string>`, with the help of the `to_string` function, and then to sort it. This avoids the need to repetidly use this `to_string` function in the `comp` function, and is more efficient.